# [Explain an error]validateDOMNesting(...): <button> cannot appear as a descendant of <button>

Tags: html, reactjs

Yes, I know it is an old question. I am a complete newbie in web programming and am starting to learn reactjs.

I ran into this error recently and tried searching, but most of what I got was `"how to fix it"` but couldn't find anyone talking about `"why does it happen"`, `"why can't nested button"`.

Can someone explain me or give me some references from reputable sites about this error? I would greatly appreciate the help.

The code i was try:

```html
<button>
  Button A
  <button>Button B</button>
</button>
```

The error i was face:

[image]

Comment: It's just telling you that your nesting is invalid, an HTML button can't contain another button. There's really not much subtlety to it, what you are doing would result in invalid HTML and React is refusing to generate the invalid structure.

Comment: @DBS I know, in theory the buttons should still work, but I want to know why they can't be nested?

Comment: Simply: Because that's what the specification says. To be technical, a button can only be nested inside a parent which accepts ["Phrasing content"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content). In terms of **why**, you'd have to ask the people who worked on the original spec, but it's likely due to nested buttons being quite misleading (E.g. if you click the inner button, logically the outer button would also be clicked, but that may or may not be the desired result)

Comment: @DBS According to the documentation, <button> does not accept "Interactive content". But it seems it still accepts the <a> tag even though it's an "Interactive content".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, a button cannot contain an `<a>` in valid HTML. Wether or not React warns you about it isn't really that important, if it's invalid then browsers may handle it inconsistently (browsers often try to automatically fix broken markup, but each one may do so differently) and you may create issues that take hours to debug later. Better to stick to valid code on the first pass, regardless of wether your editor/library specifically prevents it or not.